# Google API inserted via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a HTML page and as part of my assignment I must rip down the HTML page and rebuild it with Javascript. I have created the outlay of my site in javascript and now I want to add some functionality.

On the following page I wish to add a google map API and display it in the 'MainWindow', The function is called on a sideMenu and has been tested and works.

```
function MainBody() {
var x = document.getElementById("mainWindow");

x.style.width = "1200px";
x.style.height = "750px";
x.style.position = "absolute";
// started using 'zIndex' to 1. orginising on the site and 2. visually show where everything is meant to be in the code
x.style.zIndex = "0";
x.style.margin = "0px 0px 0px 300px";
x.style.background = "#c01e0c";
x.style.border = "thick solid #901709";
x.style.borderWidth = "10px";
}





function setUpListener2() {
document.getElementById("listItem3").addEventListener("click", Option3, false);
}




function Option3() {
    var subX1 = document.getElementById("mainWindow");

    var map = document.createElement('DIV');
    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 8
        });
    }

    subX1.appendChild(map);
    map.style.zIndex = "1";


}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I want to add the google API to the function, its not appearing on the 'mainWindow'

Comment: Do you want to add in script in the same way you set up your html?

Comment: Yeah, alot of the API's have alot of HTML in them, however I am not using any HTML upto this point, I want to create the page through javascript only, I have seen some posts about inserting the HTML into a script and doing it from there, but Im not sure how to do that in practicality

Comment: Can you show us what you want to add to the page, rather than just say "the Google API"?

Comment: @Archer The function 'option3' included the script given out in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

```
var my_google_script = document.createElement('script');

my_google_script.setAttribute('src','https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY');

document.head.appendChild(my_google_script);
```

Comment: So I have taken your answer and edited it, I am not appending this to the head as you will see:

            var parent = document.getElementById("masterDiv");
            var subX1 = document.getElementById("mainWindow");
        parent.removeChild(subX1);

        var my_google_script = document.createElement('script');
        my_google_script.style.position = "absolute";

        my_google_script.setAttribute('src', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCzjbgHg4JMAhEcgxQePAzo2ez2vGIk4ic');

        parent.appendChild(my_google_script);